# How to know no matter what method you use to count inversions, a given set always has the same number?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, algorithms

This may be a bad question. Right now I'm learning algorithms for counting inversions. My question is, how do you know that no matter how you examine a set of numbers, you will always count the same number of inversions? In other words, is there a proof that a set of $n$ numbers (that have less than and greater than operations defined) has a finite constant number of inversions?

The textbook defines inversion as "We say that two indices $i < j$ form an inversion if $a_i$ > $a_j$"

I showed this is true to myself with examples, but examples don't prove anything.

For example you could look at $(8,9,1,2,3)$ and say the $1,2,3$ move to the front or the $8,9$ move to the back, but either way it's 6 inversions. But how do you know this is always the case?

Comment: Your question might become more accessible if you add a definition of inversion.

Comment: What you have cited (second paragraph) as defining *inversion* applies to a *sequence* of numbers, not to a *set* of numbers as mentioned in the title and first paragraph of the body of your Question.  A set has no particular ordering that you can use to apply that definition.  Judging by the last paragraph, what you really want to ask about is what happens to the number of inversions when a finite sequence is *rotated*,  changing the order of the sequence but only in terms of what starting point is used (and wrapping back around to finish just before that starting point).

Comment: @hardmath so $()$ means it's  a sequence and $\{\}$ means it's a set? What is the difference between a sequence and a set?

Comment: @Celeritas:  Yes, $(\;)$ means a sequence (in the finite case, often called a [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)).  The sequence puts its elements in a definite order (the order of *indexing*) and allows for repetitions of the same value.  The elements of a set are always distinct and are not presumed to have a specified order.  Sometimes it might be convenient to use curly braces for a sequence, but you would need to explicitly indicate an *index* for the entries to avoid confusion.

Comment: Moreover the number of inversions is not always the same when a finite sequence is "rotated".  Consider $(1,2,3)$ has no inversions, but $(3,1,2)$ is a rotation of that with two inversions.  However *parity* of the number of inversions is preserved, i.e. the number of inversions will stay even or stay odd when a rotation is performed.

Comment: @hardmath: That's only if there's an odd number of elements. A cycle of even length is an _odd_ permutation and _will_ change the parity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of inversions is, by definition, the number of *unordered* pairs $\{i,j\}$ such that $i$ and $j$ appear in the wrong order in the list.

Your example $(8,9,1,2,3)$ (not with curly braces, since it's a list rather than a set) has 6 inversions, namely $$\{1,8\}, \{1,9\} \{2,8\}, \{2,9\}, \{3,8\}, \{3,9\} $$
There are six of them no matter which order you count them in.

When you swap two adjacent entries where the smaller is to the right of the larger, exactly one of the inversions will go away (and no new one will be created). *Therefore*, counting how many such neighbor swaps you can do before the list is sorted will also tell you how inversions the original list had.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, I think I was confusing the definition of inversion with the process of sorting.